# If $G$ is a group and $K$ is a subgroup, is $gKg^{-1}$ a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My lecturer stated that If $G$ is a group and $K$ is a subgroup then $gKg^{-1}$ is a subgroup also, whilst proving the sylows theorem, I'm wondering how does this hold?

Comment: Do you know what it means to be a subgroup? A subset has to satisfy certain properties to be a subgroup. Have you tried checking if those properties are satisfied by $gKg^{-1}$?

Comment: @whacka he wrote it down without stating it so I figured it was something obvious I was missing, which is why I posted - I will try do it by definition now.

Comment: It's the kind of thing that should have been covered long before Sylow theory, which is probably why it was stated so casually. It's not necessarily obvious to the uninitiated. In particular, the map $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism and homomorphisms send subgroups to subgroups.

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$\varphi: K \to G,\; k\mapsto gkg^{-1}$$
then

$$\varphi(kk')=gkg^{-1}gk'g^{-1}=\varphi(k)\varphi(k')$$
which means that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism of groups so $gKg^{-1}=\varphi(K)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Why does a homomorphism imply it's a subgroup

Comment: This is a simple exercise for you so do it:)

Comment: @supersainx Before asking why things are true you should get into the habit of trying to prove that they are true yourself. (I am assuming based on your comment you didn't exert any effort to figure it out.) You won't always have other people or references to depend on in math.

Comment: @Whacka good advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $gk_1g^{-1}, gk_2g^{-1} \in gKg^{-1}.$ Then $gk_1g^{-1} (gk_2g^{-1})^{-1}=gk_1k_2^{-1}g^{-1} \in gKg^{-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

Just check the conditions for being a subgroup one by one.

- Is $1_G \in gKg^{-1}$ true? Yes as $1_G \in K$ and $g1_Gg^{-1} = 1_G$.
- For $h,h' \in gKg^{-1} $ do you have $hh' \in gKg^{-1}$? Yes, as $h = gkg^{-1}$ and $h' = gk'g^{-1}$ for some $k, k' \in K$ and  so $hh' = g (kk')g^{-1} \in gKg^{-1}$
- For $h \in gKg^{-1}$ do you have $h^{-1} \in gKg^{-1}$? Yes, as $h = gkg^{-1}$ and  $   hgk^{-1}g^{-1}= 1_G$.

There are shorter arguments using the criterion that a non-empty set is a subgroup if and only if it contains $h_1h_2^{-1}$, or also by showing that conjugation is an isomorphism and isomorphisms preserved subgroups (as given in another answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Theorem: Let $H$ be a nonempty subset of a group $G$. Then $H$ is a subgroup
>   of $G$ if and only if $ab^{−1} \in H$ for all $a, b \in H$.

The proof is in every book of Algebra. (Algebra of Thomas W. Hungerford
for example)

Then, let $gkg^{−1}$ and $ghg^{−1}$ with $k, h \in K$ two elements of $gKg^{−1}$. We only
have to see that, $gkg^{−1} \cdot (ghg^{−1} )^{−1} \in gKg^{−1}$:

$gkg^{−1} \cdot (ghg^{−1} )^{−1} = gkg^{−1} \cdot gh^{−1} g^{ −1} = gkh^{−1} g^{−1} \in gKg^{−1}$ ( $gh^{−1} \in K$
because $K$ is a subgroup).

Comment: Hi @capitanbet090, welcome to MSE! In the future, please consider using Latex/Mathjax to make your answers more legible. You can learn how [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).